# XMPP - Spring Integration: Does the spring application run an embedded XMPP server

Tags: java, spring, xmpp, spring-integration

I'm trying to integrate instant messaging in my application that is based on the usual Spring-Maven stack. Two possibilities that I've come across are to either use raw Smack (igniterealtime.org) or go for the spring-integration support for XMPP (which is also based on Smack). My question is; "Is it required to run an XMPP server like openfire alongside or is there a possibility of the XMPP server running embedded within my application running on tomcat?". What would be an efficient scheme for the scenario? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Smack (and therefore Spring Integration XMPP) is just an API (Client) for that protocol and what you need to know and configure is `XmppConnection` and particular `host/port` to connect.

To right an application based on those component you don't need to run an XMPP server.

For example we tested Spring Integration against regular Google Chat.

So, yes: Spring Integration doesn't run Embedded Server and even doesn't require an external to be run for you locally.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response @ArtemBilan. I suppose I'll have to read more on this topic before actually going for implementing it. Would it be possible to refer to a resource that explains the full architecture required for implementing an autonomous chat application (integrated as a part of a server application) without having to use third party XMPP server (such as google). I'm still trying to understand the big picture so please bear with me if my question doesn't make a lot of sense. Thanks

Comment: Also, In case an XMPP server is not required to be run at all, what would be the `host/port` referring to?

Comment: For the XMPP adapter the server must be present somewhere anyway. And yes: OpenFire is good server for the private chat environment. Please, refer to their docs and their forums on the http://www.igniterealtime.org. That is fully different story and is already out of Spring Integration scope.

Comment: Thank you @ArtemBilan, that clears up a big confusion for me. I'll dig it further